# ASP.NET-MVC5 input multiple files

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC-5 and i have a button that lets me select multiple files for input, so it works with this code

```
<input type="file" name="file" multiple>
```

How do i fetch the files to use them within my program logic in the [HttpPost] action from the controller?

Comment: Please note that the [tag:model-view-controller] tag is intended for questions about the *pattern*. Use [tag:asp.net-mvc] and/or one of the version-specific tags when asking questions about ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you get the uploaded files from `HttpPostedFileBase` array in controller action.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase[] uploadedfiles)
        {
            try
            {
                // Loop through array fro getting files
                foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
                {
                    // get current file name
                    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    //Saving the file in relative path (server folder)
                    file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filename));
                    string filepathtosave = "Images/" + filename;

                    /* code for saving the image into database */

                }

                ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded successfully.";
            }
            catch
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Error while uploading the files.";
            }
            return View();
        }
```